# Is it possible to submit files built by Jenkins to a Perforce stream that is different than the stream the workspace sync'd from?

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, devops, unreal-engine4

I am building a modified Engine (UE4) for game development, and I want to submit the binaries to a different stream (i.e., Jenkins syncs from a stream like `//Game/Engine/...` and I want to submit to a stream like `//Game/EngineBinaries/...`) Presumably, this is done using the p4 publish command via the P4 plugin...

I've played with Jenkins' built-in syntax generator but I've had no luck so far. The job doesn't *fail*, but it also does not submit.

My latest attempt looks like:

```
 p4publish credential: 'perforce-creds', publish: submit(delete: false, description: 'Submitted by Jenkins. Build: ${BUILD_TAG}', modtime: false, onlyOnSuccess: true, paths: '', purge: '', reopen: false), workspace: streamSpec(charset: 'none', format: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-${EXECUTOR_NUMBER}', pinHost: false, streamName: '//Game/EngineBinaries/main')
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that runs into this, the issue for me was the `onlyOnSuccess` flag. It reads the job status, which will never be 'SUCCESS' until the job is done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).